# Query to get the range of IDy in IDx

Tags: sql

I have two tables: Table A is something like
IDx  ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC

Table B is something like
IDy IDx ColumnD ColumnE ColumnF

One IDy can only be under one IDx. But one IDx can include many IDys. The IDys in one IDx may or may not be continous.

For example the table B might be

```
IDy IDx |
 6    10 |
 5    10 |
 17   10 |
 8    10 |
 9    10 |
 18   10 |
 27   10 |
 38   10 |
 39   10 |
 7    10 |
 40   12 |
 37   10 |
 36   20 |
...   ...
```

If the user give an IDx as 10 and the batch size as 3, I should return all the range for IDx 10 which is larger than 3. For this case, it should return

```
IDx RangeStart RangeEnd
10   5            9
10   37           39    (Since IDy 40 is for IDx 12 and IDy 36 is for IDx 20)
```

The last grey area in the result I want to achieve. For example, in the original table (the first grey area), for IDx 10, it has 4 contiguous range, 5-9, 17-18, 27, 37-39. Only for range 5-9 and 37-39, the size is larger or equal than the batch size 3(an input by user). So in the result, it return the range start, range end as (5, 9 and 37 39)

I have no clue to how to write the query yet and I need the query to be ran as fast as possible. Is there any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The statement that makes it most clear to me that you have not learnt the basic principles of relational/SQL databases is this: "The table is also not sorted". A table is a set of values which you can query in all sorts of ways, it has no order. I suggest reading some basic introductions and tutorials, and you will probably find this query very simple.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? What is a range? What is a batch? How does the order of tuples affect your result?

Comment: The last grey area in the result I want to achieve. For example, in the original table (the first grey area), for IDx 10, it has 4 contiguous range, 5-9, 17-18, 27, 37-39. Only for range 5-9 and 37-39, the size is larger or equal than the batch size 3(an input by user). So in the result, it return the range start, range end as (5, 9 and 37 39)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well you are trying to get the group of at least 3 sequential values.
As it's not specified the version of SQLServer you are using I assume it's SQLServer 2012 or better.
In those condition one possibility is

```
WITH A AS (
  SELECT IDx, IDy
       , NextY = LEAD(IDy, 1, IDy)
                 OVER (Partition BY IDx ORDER BY IDy)
  FROM   tableB
), B AS (
  SELECT IDx
       , IDy
       , NextY
       , block = SUM(CASE WHEN IDy + 1 = NextY THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                 OVER (Partition BY IDx ORDER BY IDy)
  FROM   A
)
SELECT IDx
     , RangeStart = Min(IDy)
     , RangeEnd = Max(NextY)
FROM   B
WHERE  IDy + 1 = NextY
GROUP BY IDx, Block
HAVING Count(1) >= (3- 1)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/435e1/16)

The division of the `CTE` is only for readability.
The first `CTE` add a field with the next value of IDy for the same IDx.
The second one create a ranking in the table, e.g. for all the rows with sequential value block will be the same.
The main query use the rank to group the data. The `HAVING` condition is on 2 instead of 3 because the value of `MAX(NextY)` in the second row is the third in the sequence as NextY is the next value id IDy, the `WHERE` condition remove the rows where the sequence is broken.